# VEGA Sunburst display label name on arcs

Tags: vega

does anyone have an idea on how to display label names on the arcs for the https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/sunburst/ example?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vega's [**text**](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/text/) mark has properties *radius* and *theta* that can show text in polar coordinates. For example see [Vega radial tree example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/radial-tree-layout/)

For sunburst diagram, this text block renders text similar to the radial tree example:

```
{
  "type": "text",
  "from": {"data": "tree"},
  "encode": {
    "enter": {
      "text": {"field": "name"},
      "fontSize": {"value": 9},
      "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
      "align": {"value": "center"}
    },
    "update": {
      "x": {"signal": "width / 2"},
      "y": {"signal": "height / 2"},

      "radius": {"signal": "(datum['r0'] == 0 ? 0 : datum['r0'] + datum['r1']) / 2"},

      "theta": {"signal": "(datum['a0'] + datum['a1']) / 2"},

      "angle": {"signal": "datum['r0'] == 0 ? 0 : ((datum['a0'] + datum['a1']) / 2) * 180 / PI + (inrange(((datum['a0'] + datum['a1']) / 2) % (2 * PI), [0, PI]) ? 270 : 90)"},

      "tooltip": {"signal": "datum.name + (datum.size ? ', ' + datum.size + ' bytes' : '')"}
    }
  }
}
```

Note: *theta* is in radians but *angle* is in degrees.

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQXEACOAA8kCHABs4OtgDMdSHRBxIocALSWGJkzXFkdipLJokEx0TJABPNgZMHUs2RR0YGjg-RVgaKCCdWSRMKmkQAHcaWXo0ADYABgqZeBoyLHKqmQdZAO80ARkkKLYIGgAvODQQcQkhmWzctABtUHEjIfRMRThxkAZFE2HJ-ktQlZExSRllpHEIWMUEGdBMMJxFkAhTtUsw-IBrOHf0YvyHFbiTAAaW+wwBcCBIAAvlJbvdHgC1GoJPlLEkTLJhn1BvkxIpMGhQOi4JjhsQggwhrCngNFrNaWR5lt0AAmHQAKh0AAUAJIwuGM5nDIolGA6Ag6VkwgC6XQgMxASAq+UUKq6AEZVVqJnBVDB8mlMYCQDLoWa5U8MmYFagGfMEI8oGwTHF8ncHsM4m0gvlZGxkF4iXIciglis1iSyeh5PqBSA-N5FqAuIhHrkmGZuqyVdDzTJkIoPraGR7HkhUmjFAHgzthstVvHIc75MHIZhksH9MG+kzfehRfQJVL4z8U3VhehavVopLpTT0R4e9anS63TIo1iY3rSjTMGwXWocD2J-2Q5gGAhKA7zABqHQACkml8oOPMAH4dAByKTfnT358rzff8-yYMIOwgL8dFQb8vwAShhGkGBwSZkyeXICW0MgzGDTdhmVJtxFkLCcNQYkMS3JUtRpLxxGSAAlfwaAYW1yNJSi1XjSIO0URiAhY3CKOGRRqJkZ5qy+YMKRMKkRUSDt43EtgvgAdWKUoyJAaTZNQCpKAEGl+i8eRu007TFgqPMajYUhFB7ZZlLQ8zhLgLEaSU1T1INMzKUWVlDOMgwpN8tANTzKz4U9JYDEJDdq2uTS63DRsaWbNhW009tO00jt9EJTS8PQG941iIEAGU6WCmTFgAThpJgkAgUkvCckL0AQYpZBwmkggnKqdJAJwgU7Kz1hQnI0NM8c+xZQovOHecZDHIUz2nLAFvjPx+NYlbZqfHJL2mL81S-GUdAAXnOnQKh0T8bpgwCjpOs6AIOhAno1U64I2vd4CmTTe0nEB9ovd6v2VU6QMe8HPplb653jM5sLQwGz2h56Lqum67ugx8QcO8GKkh17QaOpBYfhqVvq5DUAA4bslPkQIfLxEzIOAH056GIZerI3rJimFu+gBSR92S5Pk4N-aZqh5Xk4duqUAHZ7p0GqKgQvcDxMI8Txm7Y3uvBZmcA186UVn8-xJl9gPvKCwIgqCYK-eDELzM0gA)

[image]